# Assign Oracle database value as filter in Salesforce query

Tags: iics

I have an Informatica Cloud mapping that has to query Salesforce data. The query has a filter clause where 'LastModifiedDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:30'. Now instead of hardcoding value =30, we want to fetch the value for days from a table value in Oracle. How can this be done in Informatica Cloud without using parameter files?